# Azure Billing - Deprecated plan

Tags: azure

This morning I am getting the following message "This account is on a deprecated billing system. Contact Support to move it to the new system." when I open my subscription blade in the portal.  When I try to submit a billing support ticket it just hangs while trying to bring up a support plan, which should not be necessary for a billing question anyway.  For now it appears that the subscription is still working, but this seems like it will go badly.  Please advise.

Comment: We're seeing the same thing. Appears that Azure is having an issue with billing details. I'd recommend filing a support ticket if you urgently need it, or just wait since they're probably already working on it.

Comment: Transient issue due to service outage. Will be irrelevant once outage is over.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue (North Europe region). Waiting..

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is an outage in Azure: https://twitter.com/AzureSupport/status/1036970068058562560. All you can do for now is wait.

Answer (score 1):

There is simply no way to create a ticket in the technical assistance ticket portal, I get the same for the last 11 a.m.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with one of the subscriptions I own. Getting the message: This account is on a deprecated billing system. Contact Support to move it to the new system.

By personal experience it should be a matter of waiting it out, since the resources on that subscription are completely offline and they are not even in the affected region. To follow progress on it go to [status.azure.com](http://status.azure.com) or follow them on twitter [Azure Support](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport). 41 minutes ago, there is still no definite resolution.